# Iterating through a foreach loop looking for a value

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I'm using a list object and trying to iterate through it to get the total sales from the day. Iterating through the objects and then adding the total sales.

```
//create a method to get daily revenue
public void GetDailyRevenue(PizzaOrder order)  
{
  //for each increments the total daily revenue (sale)
  //then increments the total revenue for each order
  //OrderList always have pizzaorder objects stored var only messing up here
  foreach (PizzaOrder po in OrderList)
  {
     dailyRevenue += order.GetAmountDue(po.NumberOfPizzas, po.NumberOfCokes);
  }
   //check what is the value of dailyRevenue here
}
```

what code do I need to check the value for daily revenue? It's not iterating through the loop. When I output it is saying that total daily revenue is 0.

I'm new so I really need help. Thanks!

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the method and inspect `OrderList`. Where does that variable come from, and what has the parameter `PizzaOrder order` to do with that method?

Comment: To answer this question, you (or anyone else) will need to look at the following: what is `dailyRevenue` and how is it declared? What is the code of `GetAmountDue`? What is `OrderList`, how is it declared, and what is the content of the list when you call the method? If you can identify these things and walk through the code yourself, you'll probably work out the answer.

Comment: "Do a search.  For free pizza.  Then see if it comes out this drive."

Comment: Welcome to SO. I can see that you have asked 3 questions about pizza today..... You should atleast tag the correct answers in your other questions as answered. And you should show the getAmountDue function so we can see the error. And good luck with your homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code its not very clear why your passing in a pizzaorder and not using it.
Maybe you should add it to the orderlist and then check that your method getamountdue works correctly

For example:

```
//create a method to get daily revenue
public void GetDailyRevenue(PizzaOrder order)  
{
  //for each increments the total daily revenue (sale)
  //then increments the total revenue for each order
  //OrderList always have pizzaorder objects stored var only messing up here
  OrderList.Add(order);
  foreach (PizzaOrder po in OrderList)
  {
     dailyRevenue += order.GetAmountDue(po.NumberOfPizzas, po.NumberOfCokes);
  }
   //check what is the value of dailyRevenue here
}
```

Comment: I figured out my issue! It was a stupid logical error on my part lol. I forgot to pass my PizzaOrder object (order) to my list from my click_event. Thanks for the advice though!